# Same person with two accounts

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

This user, [Conner Watson](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/2704/conner-watson), and this user, [Conner](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/2705/conner), are the same user as evidenced by having the same email address seen [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/revisions/6856/1) and [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6852/is-it-better-to-play-the-keyboard-standing-or-sitting#comment9409_6855). I'm not quite sure how he did this or even *why* he did this. Is it possible to merge the two accounts? How should we respond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just merged the two accounts. Both accounts were marked as unregistered so that's presumably how he was able to somehow create two.

Comment: An unregistered account is tied to an IP address, so this can happen if the same person logs in, say, from home and work, or one of those and his phone.  Registration fixes that class of problems.

Comment: @Monica I think it is or was tied to a cookie, so potentially even more volatile than an IP.