# Can a single user have multiple accounts on a single SE? (Account merge possibly needed)

Tags: support, user-accounts

Related to [Same person with two accounts](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/397/same-person-with-two-accounts)?

---

Between 30 December 2020 and 5 January 2021, there are 5 questions from "roro", which are tied to 4 unregistered "roro" accounts that appear to be separate, but which share the same user icon.

**Questions**

1. [How should left and right hand by synchronized in Chopin Nocturne in C# Minor [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/109164/how-should-left-and-right-hand-by-synchronized-in-chopin-nocturne-in-c-minor)
2. [Question about speed [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/109266/question-about-speed)
3. [question about distributing notes over long run in Chopin C# Minor Nocturne [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/109274/question-about-distributing-notes-over-long-run-in-chopin-c-minor-nocturne)
4. [question about shifting hands for scales [duplicate]](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/109368/question-about-shifting-hands-for-scales)
5. [How should one play those codas?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/109419/how-should-one-play-those-codas)

**User profiles**

a. [roro #74120](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/74120/roro) (question 1)
b. [roro #74175](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/74175/roro) (questions 2 and 3)
c. [roro #74226](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/74226/roro) (question 4)
d. [roro #74253](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/74253/roro) (question 5)

**Shared user icon**

[image: "roro" user icon]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user is unregistered, which you can see on their user page:

[image]

They don't really have an account, so every time browser cookies are cleared, the system forgets who they are. A bit inconvenient if you ask me; you have to type your name and email address every time, and you can't edit old questions or reply to comments or answers. But not forbidden; in particular, the accounts aren't able to vote for each other.

♦ moderators can't merge accounts anymore; that's only done by Stack Exchange staff, upon request of the user themselves.

Comment: Is the icon based on the user name and password? (That would explain why they're identical, which is part of what confused me. I assumed they were uniquely generated each time.)

Comment: Email address, if my memory serves me well: https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/gravatar/info

Comment: ...and by "password" I mean "email address", of course. :-)